# リモートのMariaDBにmysqlコマンドで接続すると一瞬だけ繋がってすぐ切れる

Tags: mariadb

リモートのCent OS7上でDockerコンテナを起動し、その中でMariaDBを動かしています。

このリモートのMariaDBにmysqlコマンドで接続しようとすると、一瞬だけ繋がってすぐ接続が切れます。

リモート側の設定の問題だと思うのですが、どのあたりを確認し、設定を変更すればよいでしょうか？

## 現在わかっていること

ローカルでmysqlコマンドを叩くと、次のエラーがでたり出なかったりします。
`ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading authorization packet', system error: 54 "Connection reset by peer"`

運良く接続できた場合、SQLを何か実行しようとすると先ほどのエラーか、次のエラーが出ます。
`ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query`

Docker上のMariaDBは`/usr/bin/mysqld_safe &`で起動

`/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log`には起動時のログしか出ていない

(2015-10-19追記)

DockerのホストはCentOS 7.1.1503です。

```
$ cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)
```

Dockerコンテナはdocker.io/centos(IMAGE:ce20c473cd8a)を元に作成しています。

MariaDBと手元のPC間はインターネット経由です。

利用者は自分だけで、ほぼ負荷はかかっていません。

DockerホストはfirewalldをOFFに、iptablesをONにしています。

```
$ sudo systemctl status firewalld
firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

$ sudo systemctl status iptables
iptables.service - IPv4 firewall with iptables
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/iptables.service; enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since <起動した時刻>
   Main PID: <PID> (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/iptables.service
```

Comment: MariaDB が使用するポート番号はデフォルトで 3306 だと思いますが、このポートを他のプロセスが使用しているという様な事はないでしょうか？

Comment: コネクションがリセットされる現象はいろんな原因が考えられます。つぎの点をがわかると見てる方から回答がつきやすくなると思いますので、書ける範囲で、追記してみてください。

* OS/MariaDB のバージョン
* ネットワーク環境 (同一LAN なのか VM環境か、インターネット越しかなど）
* 利用状況 （どのくらいの人数がどのくらいの頻度で使っているなど）
* 動かすまでにやったこと　（どのように構築したか、MariaDB の設定内容、Etc...）

Comment: @argus さん：ポート3306が別のプロセスにとられている時は、MariaDB自体が起動せず、ログにも「Address already in use」が記録されるので、その線は問題なさそうです

Comment: ありがとうございます。これは参考になるかどうか分かりませんが、同じ現象(lost connection)が発生したエラーレポートです。[The container launches multiple mysqld processes in a loop](https://github.com/Painted-Fox/docker-mariadb/issues/9) 途中から割り込みが入っていて、最初に問題を報告した人のエラーが解消されたのかどうかが不明なままで終わっています。

Comment: @take88 さん：いろいろ、追記しました。

Comment: MariaDB はデフォルトのまま使ってるのでしょうか？my.cnf とかいじってませんか？その中の設定値が重要かもしれません。 同時接続数とかMaxパケットサイズ、各種タイムアウトの設定が正しくないと、意図せずリセットされる可能性があると思います。あとインターネット経由ということは間にファイアウォールやルーターがあると思います。アクセスポリシーで通信を遮断（この場合は途中で切断）している可能性はありませんか？思いつくのはこんなところです。

Comment: あと こちらのURLが参考になるかもしれません。→ [Lost connection to MySQL server during query が出たときの対処](http://qiita.com/domekichi/items/1466756e3759c9bd9f41)